# Best way of dealing with socket reading and writing to database using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcplistener

I have written a c# code to listen to a port (using TCP Listener) and write data to database (SQL server). My current approach involves the following :

- Create a thread when new device entry arrives.
- Read the data from the stream and write to DB.

This all works fine till 4-5 devices send data to port. Once this is exceeded the full approach fails.

Just wanted to know if there are any alternatives for this. 
I think one approach would be to have one set of threads writing to a queue and another set of threads(limit to 3-4) reading from the queue and writing to DB.

Comment: Could you show the code where you set up the socket to listen on?

Comment: Your approach is right use a Que right a Lister on it which would save it on the db , I have done the same on my project works fine.

Comment: How long does the db write take? How long is the client connected?

Comment: Which fails, the creating of additional threads for the device, or, the database connections?

Comment: its failing on saving to db part as the connections will be limited

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a blockingcollection where you can have multiple threads adding data and multiple threads reading that data.Because it is blocking the threads will be very efficient while waiting for new data.

For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx